# record a phone call's both sides voice in separate files

Tags: android, android-intent

is it posible to record a phone call's both sides voice in separate files,I have tried this code

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_UPLINK);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

and

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_DOWNLINK);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the mobile platforms I've worked with don't support simultaneous input streams from separate sources. In the voice call recording scenario, the audio is typically coming from some sort of splitter in the voice processing chain, so I don't see any technical limitation that would prevent separate recordings of uplink and downlink; it just hasn't been implemented.

Short answer: no. Nothing that will work on all Android phones.

Comment: Sorry if I led you to believe that I know of any Android phones where this use-case works. I don't - but I can't rule out the possibility that such phones exist.

Comment: I am accepting this answer but still need more specific answer